# What’s the difference between the three ‘rechtlich’, ‘rechtmäßig’ and ‘gesetzlich’?

Tags: meaning, difference, usage, adjective

The English term *legal* may be roughly interpreted in the following senses:

1. supported by the law  (legal rights)
2. required by the law   (legal obligation)
3. of the administration of justice  (such as in *legal issues*)

I am wondering how to interpret the three German terms *rechtlich, rechtmäßig, gesetzlich* with the preceding three entries.

Besides, do the following terms *rechtlicher Vertreter*, *gesetzlicher Vertreter* and *Rechtsvertreter* designate the identical notion, or is there a difference among them?

Answer (score 6):

In fact there are differences, at least if you take *rechtlich*, *rechtmäßig* and *gesetzlich* as technical terms.

*Rechtlich* is simply the generic adjective to the noun "*Recht*" (law), so it has the broadest meaning of these terms. It doesn't qualify the object in matters of law (e.g., lawful / illegal), but simply connects the noun it pertains to to the legal sphere.

*Rechtmäßig* describes something as in accordance with the law. In german colloquial language, "*legal*" (stressed on the **a**) is used more often; it's synonymous to *rechtmäßig*.

*Gesetzlich* has a narrower meaning - it says something is in accordance with the written law that was officially enacted. The background is that there are different sources of law: *Gesetze* (statutes / bills / acts) concerning the whole population, and e.g. *Verträge* (contracts) as legal agreements between individuals. In colloquial language, "gesetzlich" may also be used synonymously with "*rechtmäßig*".

On that background, the terms *rechtlicher Vertreter*, *gesetzlicher Vertreter* and *Rechtsvertreter* indicated different meanings, too.

The "*rechtliche Vertreter*" (representative / agent) may act for someone else in legal matters, for example negotiating contracts. It's still a very broad term, and it doesn't indicate the source for that mandate - it may be itself based on a contract, too, or on statutes / acts.

The *gesetzliche Vertreter* pertains to a subset of the "rechtliche Vertreter" - those agents with a "statutory" mandate. E.g. the parents are "gesetzliche Vertreter" in relation to their children according to the German Civil Law Code.

Regarding "*Rechtsvertreter*", this may denote a "rechtlicher Vertreter" when used in colloquial language. But usually, this is someone who has the mandate to act in behalf of someone else **in a specific legal matter**, e.g. an attorney who files a suit for his client. The lawyer's mandate usually is restricted to that specific matter, while the legal mandate of the "gesetzliche Vertreter" is more universal - in the case of parents, covering almost every matter relating to their children (but this depends on the children's age).

Comment: Dabei sag ich doch immer von mir, dass ich Wurstfinger habe … ;) Ich würd ja sagen, sie es sportsmännisch, aber den Orden hast du vor ner Stunde schon bekommen =D

Comment: Like that answer. Just for the sake of completeness: "legal" is a German word as well that fits into this context. You might want to add this.

Comment: @tofro: thank you for the suggestion - i've added it to the explanation of "rechtmäßig".

Answer (score 3):

The ‘odd one out’ is *rechtmäßig*. The suffix *-mäßig* is related to the word *gemäß* meaning *according*. Therefore, if something is *rechtmäßig*, it is according to or abiding by the law.

> Sie haben *rechtmäßig* gehandelt. (Doesn’t really fit into any of your categories.)

*Rechtlich* and *gesetzlich* are somewhat similar terms. The difference between the two boils down to the difference between *Recht* und *Gesetz*. *Recht* is considered the entirety of all valid laws at any given time, so *rechlicht* is stemming from the entirety of laws.<sup>[1]</sup> A *Gesetz* is a single law, so *gesetzlich* has the implication of only referring to a single law or a defined subset of laws.

Both *rechtlich* and *gesetzlich* can be used for both your English meanings 1. and 2. The distinction is, once again, that *gesetzlich* often refers to obligations or supports stemming from single laws or small subsets thereof while *rechtlich* is often taken to mean the overarching entirety.

> Es ist *gesetzliche Pflicht* (legal obligation) eines Jeden in Notsituationen Hilfe zu leisten – § 323c StGB.
>
> Sie dazu sind *rechtlich verpflichtet* (legal obligation). (Something that is probably written in more than one place.)
>
> Aus *rechtlicher Sicht* (legal point of view; closer to meaning 1) spricht nichts gegen Ihre Ansprüche. (overarching)
>
> Ihr *gesetzlicher Anspruch* (legal right) aus dem Sozialgesetzbuch II wird anerkannt. (single law)

Anything that is related to the administration of justice is typically covered by the root *Jura* in German, the corresponding adjective is *juristisch.*

---

Therefore, a *gesetzlicher Vertreter* is a representative as specified by a single or a small subset of laws. Typically, your parents if you are a minor. A *rechtlicher Vertreter*, like the *Rechtsvertreter* is somebody who represents you in the face of the entirety of laws — a lawyer.

---

**Notes:**

[1]: *Recht* can also mean *right* or *freedom* as in *Recht auf freie Meinungsäußerung* being *freedom of speech.* This interpretation is typically *not* intended with *rechtlich.*

Comment: Donnerwetter, zwei Minuten schneller - ich muss an meinem Wurstfingerhandycap arbeiten... :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I read from Duden ,,rechtliche Gleichstellung'', which, as I understand, refers to equal treatment in juridical proceedings; and I would interpret ,,rechtlich'' as ''of administration of justice'' in this case;  but this interpretation seems to disagree with your statement '' Anything that is related to the administration of justice is typically covered by the root Jura in German, the corresponding adjective is juristisch.''  Could you lend a thought to this Duden-example?

Comment: @Lynnyo You are correct in that case and it is one I failed to consider. However, I would still think that *most* occurances of the administration bit are covered by *juristisch*.